# Why in ZFC any expressible set also exists?

Tags: set-theory

I would like to ask you a few questions about the following quote from Wang (On Denumerable Bases, 1955):

> "Zermelo's set theory is, for example, a system in which every number
>   set, if expressible in the system, can be proved to exist in the
>   system."

1) What is a number set?

2) Can someone give me more information on the link between expressibility and existence in ZFC?

3) How the proof mentioned by Wang works?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange ! This is in fact weird. I only know the concept of "constructable sets", for which the claim is obvious.

Comment: Page 61 : "number set (i.e., set of positive integers)"

Comment: @Mauro it sounds like you have enough info for an answer.  Maybe your comments plus a clarification about whether [Zermelo's original system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) was meant would settle everything.

Answer (score 3):

See Thoralf Skolem *et alii* (editors), [Mathematical Interpretation of Formal Systems (North Holland, 1955)](https://books.google.it/books?id=k_Gqsv1FB6MC&pg=PA57), page 61 :

> *number set* (i.e., set of positive integers).

In that context, "$S$ is *expressible*" means : $∀m(m∈S ↔ \varphi(m))$ for some formula $\varphi$.

Wang (page 59) refers to Bernays-Godel set theory, Quine-Hailperin theory (ordinarily known as the "New Foundations") as well as Zermelo's set theory and Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (page 64).

[Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html), using the *Infinity Axiom*, proves the existence of the set $\omega$ of natural numebrs.

Thus, it is enough to apply the *Separation Schema* to $\omega$ to prove the existence of $S$ :

> > $\exists S \ \forall m \ (m \in S \leftrightarrow m \in \omega \land \varphi(m))$.

Comment: Thank you so much Mauro, that's really clear and helpful