# Why is Skolem Theorem essentially second-order?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

The (philosophical) intuition beyond this question is that as much as the Skolemization of a $\exists \forall$ first-order formula allows to introduce a Skolem constant which refers to an arbitrary individual (namely, an individual arbitrarily picked out), so the Skolemization of a $\forall \exists $ first-order formula allows to introduce a Skolem function which (should) refers to an arbitrary function.
Nevertheless, it is well known that, while the equisatisfiability of a $\forall \exists $  first-order formula and it's Skolem Normal Form (SNF) can be proved in FOL as (where $|\phi |$ means the satisfiability of $\phi $): $$|\forall x\exists y\varphi(x,y)| \iff |\forall x\varphi(x,f(x))|$$
The logical equivalence of a first-order formula and it's SNF can be proved only in SOL (I will refer to this as Skolem Theorem), on the assumption of the Axiom of Choice (AC), as: $$\forall x\exists y\varphi(x,y) \models \exists f\forall x\varphi(x,f(x))$$ **My question is:** what is the ZFC 'assumption' (or feature) that makes Skolem theorem essentially second-order? It seems to me that the metalanguage of FOL - namely ZFC - does not allow to prove the logical equivalence between a first-order formula and it's SNF within FOL.

I will now propose a solution - but any other suggestion is welcomed. I think that this problem is closely tied up with the fact that in ZFC, while every definable set can be proved to exist (see my question [Why in ZFC any expressible set also exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363170/why-in-zfc-any-expressible-set-also-exists)), not every set that exists can be defined. Let me explain: the Skolem functions in an expanded model are by no means unique. However, if the first-order formula is like: 
 $$\forall x\exists !y\varphi(x,y)$$ 
Then the logical equivalence with it's SNF can be proved in FOL without AC as: $$\forall x\exists !y\varphi(x,y) \models \forall x\varphi(x,f(x))$$ Moreover, this last equivalence defines the Skolem function for the antecedent formula. This is due to the fact that in ZFC one can define a selection set *t* (namely, a Skolem function) for another set *s* iff  *s* contains some definable element [Fraenkel 1973, Foundations of Set Theory]. In the example above, *s* contains some definable element because $\exists !y$ is a singleton. Yet, the ZFC proof of the Skolem theorem requires to consider also model with no definable elements - such as the set of all well-ordering of the set of the  real numbers. At this point, AC is required to guarantee the existence of a (Skolem) function which cannot be defined. Is this correct?
If this argument is sound, then there is a tension with the initial (philosophical) intuition. Let me explain: to prove the logical equivalence of $\forall \exists $ first-order formulas and their SNF we need AC - and so also SOL - cause there are models with no definable elements where the values of Skolem functions cannot be defined. Yet, to prove the logical equivalence of $\exists \forall$ first-order formulas and their SNF neither AC nor SOL are required. But how is it possible that the added Skolem constant denotes a non definable element? Going back to the initial (philosophical) intuition, it seems that in the metalanguage of FOL - namely ZFC - we can refer to arbitrary objects but not to arbitrary functions. Why so? This last question is tricky: while the former proof requires AC - and so it's carried out in ZFC - the latter proof can be given in a (pure) model-theoretic settings (such as for Henkin theory). 


P.S. I have been thinking about this question for a while. Please, feel free to ask me any clarificatory questions.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here: one is the broad question about Skolem functions; the second is a specific one about choice. You also have a couple of typos ($\forall x\exists x$ should probably be $\forall x\exists y$? that occurs several times in the text), and I also don't know what $|\psi|$ means when $\psi$ is a formula.

Comment: Let me answer the part about choice, so we can focus on the actual question at hand. Yes, Skolem functions are equivalent to the axiom of choice, in fact to *global choice*. Look at the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ means $x=y=\varnothing$ or $y\in x$. Then a Skolem function for this is a global choice function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you for the corrections. By $|\varphi |$ I mean the satisfiability of $\varphi $. About your second post: is it correct to say that, while $\forall x\exists y\varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \exists f\forall x\varphi(x,f(x))$ is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice, instead $\forall x\exists y\varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x\varphi(x,f(x))$ is equivalent to the Axiom of Global Choice? I'm also looking forward to your answer about my general question about Skolem functions.

Comment: There's a problem with writing $\exists f\forall x\varphi(x,f(x))$. The $\exists$ quantifier is meant to quantify over sets (i.e. a first-order quantifier), so either you claim that $f$ is a set, in which case its domain is a set containing all other sets, which is impossible; or $\exists f$ is a second-order quantifier. In either case, this is not the statement of the axiom of choice.

Comment: I get it. Now, I would like to bring your attention to my final question, namely the comparison between the logical equivalence of $\forall \exists$  and $\exists \forall$ first-order formulas and their Skolem Normal Form. In the first case, the equivalence can be established only in SOL on the assumption of the Axiom of Choice, which guarantees the existence of a (Skolem/choice) function even in the models with non-definable elements - and so where the value of the Skolem functions cannot be defined. In the second case, the equivalence can be established in FOL without neither AC nor SOL.

Comment: My question is: how is it possible that the logical equivalence of $\exists \forall$ first-order formulas and their Skolem Normal Form avoids the problem of models with non-definable elements? Indeed, as you know, the equivalence of $\exists \forall$ first-order formulas and their Skolem Normal Form can be proved in FOL by replacing $\exists$ with a Skolem constant (as for Henkin theories), which is a 0-ary function. Yet, as soon as we consider $\forall \exists$ first-order formulas (where $\exists$ is replaced by an n-ary Skolem function) both AC and SOL are required to prove the equivalence

Comment: This difference between the $\exists \forall$ and $\forall \exists$ cases makes me believe that there is an assumption (or feature) of the metalanguage of FOL - namely ZFC - which makes the logical equivalence between $\forall \exists$ first-order formulas and their Skolem Normal Form essentially second-order... I hope this makes sense to you @AsafKaragila, thanks for your time